# Finding pairs of rows with matching column sub-strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of them is named `'log_text'.`  I want to find pairs of rows that have matching strings in this column.

For example, if `'log_text'` has these strings

```
 Device remove ID#xxx  
 Device remove ID#yyy  
 Device remove ID#zzz  
 Device arrive ID#xxx  
 Device arrive ID#yyy 
 Device arrive ID#zzz
```

Goal:
I would like to get the rows containing `'Device remove ID#xxx'` and `'Device arrive ID#xxx'` and be able to do stuff with their other columns, then repeat this for rows containing `'Device remove ID#yyy'` and `'Device arrive ID#yyy'`, etc.

What I've tried is using `iterrows()`, find the `ID#` of the current row, drop that row from the table, and find the first row that contains the matching ID# string.

```
    for index, row in temp_df.iterrows():
        log_string = row['log_text']
        id_text = log_string.partition("ID#")[2]
        temp_df.drop(row)
        match = temp_df[temp_df['log_text'].str.contains(id_text)]
        # Somehow stash the 2 rows together somewhere? 
            # like stash[index,1] = row; stash[index,2] = match;
        temp_df.drop(match)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'log':['Device remove ID#xxx',
    ...:                           'Device remove ID#yyy',
    ...:                           'Device remove ID#zzz',
    ...:                           'Device arrive ID#xxx',
    ...:                           'Device arrive ID#yyy',
    ...:                           'Device arrive ID#zzz',],
                            'other_row':[1,2,3,42,54,6]})

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                    log  other_row
0  Device remove ID#xxx          1
1  Device remove ID#yyy          2
2  Device remove ID#zzz          3
3  Device arrive ID#xxx         42
4  Device arrive ID#yyy         54
5  Device arrive ID#zzz          6

In [14]: df_splits = df['log'].str.split(expand=True)

In [16]: df['action'] = df_splits[1]

In [17]: df['user'] = df_splits[2]

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
                    log  other_row  action    user
0  Device remove ID#xxx          1  remove  ID#xxx
1  Device remove ID#yyy          2  remove  ID#yyy
2  Device remove ID#zzz          3  remove  ID#zzz
3  Device arrive ID#xxx         42  arrive  ID#xxx
4  Device arrive ID#yyy         54  arrive  ID#yyy
5  Device arrive ID#zzz          6  arrive  ID#zzz


In [22]: for i, d in df.groupby('user'):
    ...:     print i
    ...:     print d
    ...:     print d['other_row'].sum()
    ...:     print
    ...:
    ...:
ID#xxx
                    log  other_row  action    user
0  Device remove ID#xxx          1  remove  ID#xxx
3  Device arrive ID#xxx         42  arrive  ID#xxx
43

ID#yyy
                    log  other_row  action    user
1  Device remove ID#yyy          2  remove  ID#yyy
4  Device arrive ID#yyy         54  arrive  ID#yyy
56

ID#zzz
                    log  other_row  action    user
2  Device remove ID#zzz          3  remove  ID#zzz
5  Device arrive ID#zzz          6  arrive  ID#zzz
9
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

I think you can use `.str.count` and `.loc` to do further operations

for example:

```
rows_to_filter = ['Device remove ID#xxx','Device remove ID#yyy',
'Device remove ID#zzz','Device arrive ID#xxx',
'Device arrive ID#yyy','Device arrive ID#zzz']

df.loc[df['log_text'].str.count('|'.join(rows_to_filter)) > 1, 'col'] = 'do something'
```

This will return a dataframe slice with anything with more than one occurance of your list above in any given row, you might need to tinker around with the logic as I'm not 100% what you need without a sample output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the original column and just want to sort on the last 3 characters, you can create a separate column just for this purpose.

```
df1['group'] = df1['log_text'].str[-3::]
```

This will create a copy of the 'log_text' column but only keep the last three characters.